# PHP: image won't display

Tags: php, image

I have a form that uploads data to the DB and this includes the path to the directory where images are uploaded. Everything works, except for the fact that the image won't display.

Viewing the source in my browser tells me that the image is found but I keep getting the broken image icon.

Here's my code:

```
$dir = "../uploaded_images/";

$filePath = $row['images_path'];
$fileArray = explode("*", $filePath);

if (count($fileArray) > 0) {
   $image = $fileArray[0];
   echo "<img src='$image' width='300px'>";
}
```

In the form you can upload multiple files. In the DB, the files get a random prefix then file name, like 3456456745654_imageName.jpg.

If multiple files are uploaded, they are split with an asterisk (*), which is why I'm exploding.

Then, to print only one image, I'm checking for the number of images relevant to a specific record then displaying only the first one.

PS. This code works for displaying all the images relevant to a selected image:

```
$dir = "uploaded_images/";

$filePath = $row['images_path'];
$fileArray = explode("*", $filePath);

foreach ($fileArray as $file) {
   if (file_exists($dir . $file)) {
      echo "<img class='images' src='$dir/$file' width='300px;'>";
   }
}
```

But that's for a different page that displays a selected vehicle's information, including all images.

I need to show only one image per vehicle on the landing page that lists all vehicles.

Comment: Is the $image = $fileArray[0]; getting the full path of the image ?

Comment: Why you wrote different code? In you first example you don`t use $dir at all.

Comment: Are you using an asterix (*) as a path separator?

Comment: If I was to make a guess I would say that you need to root your paths to the document root of your website.

Comment: @Bonner yes. It's a path seperator

Comment: Are you aware that an asterisk is a valid character for a *nix file name?

Comment: Is the uploaded_images directory stored in the document root and is it accessible to the public?

Comment: @Bonner yes and it's accessable. Like I said, if you view the vehicle details with all the images, it works just fine. But displaying only one image, it breaks.

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work.

Comment: The only reason I was asking was to ensure I had enough information to answer the question. My gut feeling was that you were missing the directory name from the path which is exactly the answer you've just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use the directory:

```
$dir = "../uploaded_images/";

$filePath = $row['images_path'];
$fileArray = explode("*", $filePath);

if (count($fileArray) > 0) {
   $image = $fileArray[0];
   if (file_exists($dir . $image)) {
      echo "<img class='images' src='$dir/$image' width='300px;'>";
   }
 }
```